# Specifying pyproj lat and lon in radians

Tags: gdal, pyproj

I'm using pyproj to do some conversions:

```
import pyproj
myprojection=pyproj.Proj('+proj=gnom +lat_0=1 +lon_0=1  +R=1.')
print myprojection(30,30)

Out: 
(0.5480783303637778, 0.6353400942474053)
```

Now I know it's possible to give  `myprojection` values in radians with:

```
myprojection(0.52359877559829882,0.52359877559829882,radians=True)
```

Is it possible to do the same when declaring the projection with `pyproj.Proj`i.e. can I specify the `lat_0` and `lon_0` in radians?

I could not find good documentation on how to write those projection declaration strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the conversion from radians to degrees in python. If you combine that with the keyword argument abilities in Proj, then you can do it like so:

```py
import math
import pyproj

myprojection = pyproj.Proj(
    proj="gnom",
    lat_0=math.degrees(0.017453292519943295),
    lon_0=math.degrees(0.017453292519943295),
    R=1.,
)
```